# Income Tax Filing for Invoices that are for client supplies/infrastructure

Tags: united-states, income-tax, small-business, state-income-tax, income-tax-refund

Can someone provide me information on how taxes are impacted in the following scenario:

- I am a web developer
- My clients are charged for infrastructure setup
  fees (such as hostnames, servers, etc)
- These fees are reflected in my invoice in addition to my hourly rate Paypal sees it all as
  income, but a large percentage is not income since it is fees for
  infrastructure/supplies for my client (that they could have paid for).

Is there documentation on how I file this difference come tax season? Is it really all considered income since I am not actually gaining any profit? I am using Paypal to do invoicing (so they send me a 1099-K).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll include the various costs you incur as expenses when you file your taxes and they won't be included in your taxable income.